# Scala actors and shared state

Tags: scala, shared-memory, actor, akka

I am trying to implement a dispatcher actor that either process the request or delegates the processing to another actor in case of failure (actually it is the exponential backoff algorithm). The dispatcher actor has a boolean variable that is used to decide how to route the processing.

Is it correct to mantain some state in the actor? What problems could happen? Should I use a transactor (akka) or STM to avoid problems? (I am using akka actors)

```
class DispatcherActor extends Actor {

   var backoff = false

   def receive = {
    case SendMessage(registrationId, message) => {
      if (backoff) {
        //put on the queue
        backoffManagerActor ! AddMessageToQueue(message)
      } else {
        httpClient.sendNotificationToClient(message, this)
      }
    }
    case BackoffCompleted => //set backoff to false
      backoff = false
    }

   def otherMethod = {
      backoff=true
   } 
}
```

Comment: You should _never_ pass your actor instance to other code, it violates the Actor Model. Pass the 'self' reference(ActorRef) and send a message back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actors should maintain state, but it's easiest to reason about them if they only change that state in response to messages or their internally-generated actions; if other entities want them to change state, they should send a message.

In your case, I'd change

```
def otherMethod { backoff = true }
```

to, within receive,

```
case BeginBackoff => backoff = true
```

and have whoever was going to call otherMethod send `BeginBackoff` instead.  (If you need to preferentially process the backoff messages, you should use the two-level receive others have demonstrated e.g. in response to your previous question about actors.)

Comment: Actually otherMethod is the method called when the request performed by the httpclient completes (nio). It is a listener method. I am using async http client. So should I replace the listener method with a message passing? Do actors process messages sequentially or concurrently? Thanks

Comment: Actors process messages sequentially, but if you use nested receives/reacts, you can preferentially pick out certain messages from the list first.  Since it's sequential, you don't have to worry about `BackoffCompleted` being run _after_ the var was set even though it should have happened first.  So you could have the listener send a message instead of setting the boolean var.  If you know you're safe from this sort of confusion, however, you might just switch to using `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean` instead of the primitive boolean to at least keep updates to the boolean straight.

Comment: @Matroska - I should add that if this is supposed to be super-high-performance and you're going to toggle the flag a lot, you probably don't want the overhead of message passing.  Scala's actors perform decently, but they definitely err on the side of correctness and ease of reasoning, not performance.